# 500 error on server could not find declared class

Tags: puppet

I am walking through some puppet tutorials. In my `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environment/production/manifests/site.pp` I have

```
node default {
  class { 'motd': }
  class { 'viminstall'}
}
```

From there I have made two modules: a `motd` module and a `viminstall` module. My error is related to my `viminstall` module. Within the `viminstall/manifests` directory I have made two files: `init.pp` and `vim.pp`. My `init.pp` has the following

```
class viminstall {
  notify { "I'm installing vim": }
  include viminstall::vim
}
```

my `vim.pp` has the following

```
class viminstall::vim {
  package { 'vim':
    ensure => 'latest'
  }
}
```

When I run `puppet agent --test` I get an error saying `could not find declared class viminstall at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What directory is the `viminstall` module in?

Comment: Its installed in /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/viminstall

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the permissions on the directory I changed the modules folder and all sub directorates where those files where stored to 755 and it ran without issue